# objected mapped to in unordered_map, is it initialized by the system?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

When using unordered_map to map to a structure, wonder if the object mapped to is initialized by the system.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with g++ 4.7.3.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct strDum {
    uint a[3];
    int id;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char cmd[100];
    std::unordered_map<std::string,strDum> mymap;
    mymap["john"].a[0] = 10;
    mymap["john"].a[1] = 20;
    mymap["john"].a[2] = 30;
    printf("%d\n", mymap[argv[1]].a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an insertion is performed when using [std::unordered_map::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), the mapped value is [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
>   key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.
>
> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized
>   (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and
>   a reference to it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `std::unordered_map` `mymap` in following lines

```
mymap["john"].a[0] = 10;
mymap["john"].a[1] = 20;
mymap["john"].a[2] = 30;
```

Comment: I didn't initialize all the values, so I wonder what happened to the field I didn't manually initialize.